# How to make a button non-working until another React Native TypeScript button is pressed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, button, react-hooks

I have such a problem, I need code so that after pressing one button, another React Native TypeScript button is available for pressing

I tried many things, but nothing came out

Comment: When you say you've tried things that didn't work it would be good to share what you tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep track of some information, how you do it can depend on the context.

But essentially during the rendering you need to know whether the button has been pressed or not. The most basic form of this would be

```
const [hasBeenPressed, setHasBeenPressed] = useState(false)
```

Then when the first button gets clicked you do whatever the button needs to do plus call `setHasBeenPressed(true)`

The second part is using `hasBeenPressed` to in some way affect the second button. Again in the simplest form would be `<button disabled={!hasBeenPressed}/>`. I don't know about React Native button specifically.

This was as a simple example, if you want to look at it further, maybe you can derive whether the second button should be disabled or not based on some data that may have changed or been set by the first button or some other way, but those are more details. Hopefully this can get you started.